# Spring 3.5 Session Bean Lifecycle

Tags: spring, session, javabeans

What triggers Spring's Session Bean to exist in the container, and what removes it?  Basically, I want to understand the web flow's effect on Session Bean.

Comment: No HttpSessionListener in the codebase so I removed the faulty answer.

Answer (score 1):

Session bean is created when you try to access it from view for the first time or you want to access a bean that depends on it. It is stored in HTTP session so it is removed when session expires or is explicitly destroyed - this part is managed by a servlet container rather than spring.

Comment: Hmm.. to explicitly destroy a session in Spring 3.5, do I just call a method that is annotated as @PreDestroy and the Servlet container will successively remove my session?

Comment: To destroy a HTTP session you need to use servlet API, not Spring API. I believe you can do it like this: 
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                session.invalidate();
            }
Usually you don't do that manually. I recommend using Spring security where you can configure logout filter to do it upon user logout. It will also happen automatically when session expires.